# Rotate a float ndarray without changing the values

Tags: python, scipy, rotation, numpy-ndarray

I'd like to rotate a numpy array like this

```
[[0.    0.... 0.771... 0. 0.162 0. ...]
 [0.987 0.... 0.074    0. 0...  0. ...]
 [...]]
```

I'm using **scipy.ndimage.rotate**.
Here is my code:

```
matrix = read_mat_file(file_name).reshape((shape[0],shape[1]))
matrix_rot = scipy.ndimage.rotate(matrix, angle=60, reshape=False, mode='constant')
```

The result is:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  8.48601683e-01 ... 6.49464144e-02  3.33448905e-02]
 [-3.74391429e-02 -3.33013694e-02 ... -4.96632874e-02 -6.57955186e-04]
 [ 2.98892084e-03  1.71639726e-03 ... 9.86108733e-04  5.91683982e-04]
 [...]]
```

However, what I really need is something like this:

```
[[0.    0.    ... 0.    ... 0. 0.074 ...  0. ...]
 [0.    0.771 ... 0.162 ... 0. 0.    ...  0. ...]
 [...]]
```

What causes this? How could I avoid those unnecessarily generated 'small values'?

Thanks!

Comment: You can define some tolerance threshold and simply set all values below it to zero.